# A story involving a pub, a pea-soup fog, and time-travel?

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

A guy sits in a pub on a foggy night, goes out, maybe crosses the street, or re-enters the pub and is in a different time. Not a Callahan story.

Comment: May I ask you to [edit] your question to add more details about this story, such as when you read this, where, and in what language? There is a fair bit of guidance [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question).

Comment: This does sound vaguely familiar, though - I'd be interested in more details.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy. Please make sure you've checked out the [tour], read [ask] (and possibly [answer]), as well as the [Story-ID guidelines](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info). What language did you read it in? Where were you when you read it? Medium? Etc. I hope you decide to stick around!

Comment: Just gonna leave this here in case the OP comes back to provide more details [Frequently Asked Questions About Time Travel](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0910554/)

Comment: Though the Niven is most likely, I feel that completeness demands mention of the inn (whose name escapes me) in a couple of stories by Poul Anderson.  It's central to a short story (whose title also escapes me) and tangential to _A Midsummer Tempest_.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It might be the Larry Niven story ["For a Foggy Night"](http://news.larryniven.net/biblio/display.asp?key=32):

> In one of Niven's rare stories of cross-dimensional travel, an unnamed
>   protagonist discovers the real reason that things seem so foggy on a
>   foggy night.

The story does start in a bar, and the narrator gets lost in the fog and ends up in an alternate universe. It's not time travel, though, it's travel between alternative universes.

Comment: Thank you all. It was the Niven story. Up here in the summer, sometimes in other seasons, there is a particular kind of cloud, fuzzy around the edges without much definition that seems always just slightly out of focus. I always imagined them to be portals to other dimensions or times. Somehow they evoke the memory of the Niven story.... Strangely enough, I have a copy of Tales of the Spaceport Bar on my shelf and the story is there, I just couldn't remember the collection or the story's title.

Comment: @LoonDavidson  If this is the right answer, please click the green checkmark to accept this answer.  That will give the poster (and you) some internet reputation, but more importantly it will mark the question closed.  As is, people have to click into the question and read your comment to know that you're satisfied.